# Upper bound for the multiple integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I know that the multiple integral $$\int_{R^d} (1+|\omega|^{2k})^{-1}d\omega$$ is convergent for 2k>d, but can anyone find a closed form solution, or otherwise provide a pretty tight upper bound (in terms of d and k) for it? I didn't find any clues in the calculus books.

Comment: Changing to hyperspherical coordinates gives
$$S_{d - 1} \int_0^\infty \frac {r^{d - 1}} {1 + r^{2 k}} dr,$$
which has a simple closed form.

Comment: Thanks! That helped.